# CKEditor5+React+TypeScript: TypeScript error right out of the box

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Followed the [Quick Start Guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html) and chose `InlineEditor`. Also tried `ClassicEditor`. We are just trying to render a CKEditor to get started.

We get this error:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Repos/our_project/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/attributecommand.d.ts(8,24):
',' expected.  TS1005

     6 |  * @module basic-styles/attributecommand
     7 |  */
  >  8 | import { Command, type Editor } from 'ckeditor5/src/core.js';
       |                        ^
     9 | /**
    10 |  * An extension of the base {@link module:core/command~Command} class, which provides utilities for a command
    11 |  * that toggles a single attribute on a text or an element.
```

But we are using TypeScript 4.1.3, which should support this syntax? (Note: No minimum TS version is mentioned in CKEditor docs that I could find.)

Dependencies in `package.json`:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "3.3.16",
        "@azure/msal-browser": "2.37.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "~41.2.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "~6.2.0",
        "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
        "@dnd-kit/core": "~5.0.1",
        "@dnd-kit/sortable": "~6.0.0",
        "@dnd-kit/utilities": "~3.1.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "4.11.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
        "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "2.5.8",
        "@tanstack/react-table": "8.9.3",
        "@types/file-saver": "2.0.5",
        "@types/react-color": "~3.0.6",
        "@types/text-encoding": "0.0.36",
        "apollo-cache-persist": "0.1.1",
        "date-fns": "2.16.1",
        "draft-convert": "~2.1.12",
        "draft-js": "~0.11.7",
        "export-to-csv": "0.2.1",
        "fast-sort": "2.2.0",
        "file-saver": "2.0.5",
        "filestack-js": "3.18.0",
        "graphql": "15.5.0",
        "leaflet": "1.7.1",
        "lodash.isequal": "4.5.0",
        "lodash.throttle": "4.1.1",
        "material-table": "1.69.3",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "13.0.0",
        "react-color": "~2.19.3",
        "react-contenteditable": "3.3.5",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-draft-wysiwyg": "~1.14.7",
        "react-draggable": "4.4.3",
        "react-highlight-words": "0.17.0",
        "react-image-gallery": "1.0.8",
        "react-intersection-observer": "~8.32.1",
        "react-number-format": "4.4.1",
        "react-resizable": "2.0.0",
        "react-resize-detector": "5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
        "react-scroll": "1.8.1",
        "react-slick": "0.27.12",
        "react-sortable-hoc": "2.0.0",
        "react-table": "7.5.2",
        "react-truncate": "2.4.0",
        "react-truncate-markup": "5.0.0",
        "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "1.0.2",
        "react-virtualized-dnd": "^2.5.1",
        "react-vtree": "2.0.4",
        "react-window": "^1.8.5",
        "react-window-infinite-loader": "1.0.5",
        "sanitize-html": "2.6.1",
        "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
        "source-map-explorer": "~2.5.3",
        "subscriptions-transport-ws": "0.9.18",
        "usa-state-validator": "~1.0.6",
        "uuid": "8.3.1",
        "xlsx": "0.16.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@hot-loader/react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "@testing-library/dom": "7.30.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "9.4.0",
        "@testing-library/react-hooks": "8.0.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "13.0.6",
        "@types/draft-convert": "~2.1.4",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.14",
        "@types/jspdf": "1.3.3",
        "@types/lodash.isequal": "4.5.5",
        "@types/lodash.throttle": "4.1.6",
        "@types/node": "14.11.2",
        "@types/popper.js": "1.11.0",
        "@types/react": "16.9.50",
        "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "13.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
        "@types/react-draft-wysiwyg": "~1.13.4",
        "@types/react-highlight-words": "0.16.2",
        "@types/react-image-gallery": "1.0.0",
        "@types/react-resizable": "1.7.2",
        "@types/react-resize-detector": "5.0.0",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.5",
        "@types/react-scroll": "1.8.0",
        "@types/react-slick": "0.23.4",
        "@types/react-sortable-hoc": "0.7.1",
        "@types/react-table": "7.0.22",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.3",
        "@types/react-truncate": "2.3.3",
        "@types/react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "1.0.0",
        "@types/react-window": "1.8.2",
        "@types/react-window-infinite-loader": "1.0.3",
        "@types/sanitize-html": "1.27.1",
        "@types/uuid": "8.3.0",
        "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
        "clsx": "1.1.1",
        "jest-canvas-mock": "2.3.0",
        "jest-junit": "11.1.0",
        "jsdom-worker": "~0.3.0",
        "prettier": "2.1.2",
        "react-app-rewire-hot-loader": "2.0.1",
        "react-app-rewired": "2.1.6",
        "react-hot-loader": "4.13.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
        "serve": "11.3.2",
        "ts-jest": "27.1.1",
        "typescript": "4.1.3",
        "workbox-cacheable-response": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-core": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-expiration": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-precaching": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-routing": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-strategies": "6.2.0",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "6.2.0"
    }
}
```

Usage in component:

```js
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline'
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
//...
<CKEditor
   editor={InlineEditor}
   data={`<p>${articleTitle}</p>`}
/>
//...
```

Node version: `12.22.12`
(Also didn't see a min version for this, except for custom builds, which we aren't doing yet.)

Tried nuking node_modules and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading TypeScript from `4.1.3` to `4.5.5` resolved the issue! Newer versions worked too, but `4.5.x` was the oldest that didn't produce the error.